# If (Bools = true) not executing -Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, boolean

Attempting to execute a modal segue when multiple different Bool variables are all true (activated true through IBAction button push), however, nothing is happening- here is how they are all setup-

```
UIViewController {

// INITIAL TO CHECK WHICH BUTTONS HAVE BEEN PUSHED //
var 1Check = Bool()

// Checks //
@IBAction func 1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    1Check = true
    }
```

and here is the execution-

```
viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MoveOn()
}

func MoveOn(){
    if (1Check == true && 2Check == true ...) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NewScreen", sender: nil)

    }
}
```

what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Is that your view controller from top to bottom? Are you sure the values are true? The check is happening when the view loads, before any buttons can be tapped.

Comment: Yes, how would I have it constantly check instead of only once when the view loads?

Comment: You can call MoveOn() after each button press. Do the values only change after pressing a button?

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks! - and yes. The values only change after pressing the button.

Comment: Small semantic suggestion but you should review your naming conventions to be inline with the standard.  Camel Casing usually means you begin variables and functions with a *lowercase* letter and not a number.
I'm sure future colleagues will thank you, or rather, not get on your case about it :)

Comment: @bitwit thanks for the info! will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to MoveOn() needs to be in a place where it will be called every time one of those checked values changes:

```
UIViewController {

    // INITIAL TO CHECK WHICH BUTTONS HAVE BEEN PUSHED //
    var 1Check = Bool()

    // Checks //
    @IBAction func 1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        1Check = true
        MoveOn()
    }

    viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func MoveOn(){
        if (1Check == true && 2Check == true ...) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NewScreen", sender: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again brother! Works perfect.

Comment: @Taytee Sure thing!